# vertical text centering in <a> vs <button>

Tags: html, css, button, hyperlink

I came across this behavior recently when a client reported that some of the buttons on a page had vertically centered text while others did not.

As it turns out, buttons will vertically center text inside them but links won't. Example here: http://jsfiddle.net/valentin/7EjtD/

```
a, button{
    height: 200px;
    background-color: #ff6400;
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: bold;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    border: 0;
    padding: 20px;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Is there any way to add this behavior to links as well outside of using `line-height`?

Comment: You made a button and an anchor, with the same style? What is the logic? You have to style your anchor and button different to get what you want.

Comment: @Siyah I want them to look the same but the text won't center on the link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Button aligns to the middle because is its default behavior. Your fiddle is aligning top actually. 
To make it work you can wrap your elements on an `display:table` element, like a div. Then set the button and the link to be `display:table-cell`. Then your vertical-align will work. Like this:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <a href="#">LINK</a>
    <button>BUTTON</button>
</div>
```

And the css:

```
*{
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

div.wrapper {
    display:table;
}

a, button{
    height: 200px;
    background-color: #ff6400;
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: bold;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    border: 0;
    padding: 20px;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Comment: I see, that looks like it creates the behavior I was after, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Buttons are inline-block elements, while anchors are just inline. You can use padding to achieve the same effect:

```
a
{
    padding: 91px 20px; /*  <---(height-fontSize)/2  */
    height: auto;
}
```

### [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7EjtD/4/)

Comment: Yes, that's the option I thought of using but it still puzzles me. Even if I style the link as an inline-block element, the text won't center (not that it should, that's not what inline-block does).

Answer (score 1):

TableData (`TD` AKA *cell*) are pretty damn good at default text centering ;)

**[live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/7EjtD/5/)**

```
a{
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

for clean-code-sake i'd use a special class like:

```
a.buttonAlike{
```

Answer (score -2):

Sorry folks! Didn't see he wanted to avoid line-height. Original post:

Add line-height equal to the height of your element. In this case:

```
line-height: 200px;
```

DEMO: [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/7EjtD/3/)

Comment: From the OP: "Is there any way to add this behavior to links as well outside of using line-height"

Comment: Ah, didn't see you wanted to avoid line-height. See @David solution.